# Ruby Net::SCP multiple uploads in parallel

Tags: ruby, net-ssh

I would like to upload multiple files to a remote machine in parallel. This is what I have tried so far based on the [documentation](https://net-ssh.github.io/net-scp/)

```
Net::SCP.start(ip, user) do |scp|
  channels = []
  dst = 'some_remote_location'

  stl_files.each do |f|
    channels << scp.upload(f, dst)
  end
  channels.each{|channel| channel.wait}
end
```

but I receive the following error

```
Error: #<Net::SSH::ChannelOpenFailed: open failed (1)>
```

I have also tried an alternative approach

```
Net::SSH.start(ip, user) do |ssh|
  channels = []
  dst = 'some_remote_location'

  stl_files.each do |f|
    channels << ssh.scp.upload(f, dst)
  end
  channels.each{|channel| channel.wait}
  ssh.loop
end
```

but the error is the same.

The blocking version `scp.upload!` or `ssh.scp.upload!` works as expected.

Comment: Have you tried [sftp](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-sftp)

Comment: The error seems like the `remote` does not identify `localhost`.